# Splitting a Collection into multipe collections grouped in a map using streams

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping

Let's say I have a class

```
public class Animal {
 String name;
 String species;
}
```

I would like to know if there is a good way using stream to split a `Collection<Animal>` into a `Map<String, Collection<Animal>>` grouping different animals by species.

I can do it the old way but I suppose there is an use for streams in there. My main problem is that I don't know how to "create a list on the go".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to something like this:

```
Map<String, Collection<Animal>> collect = animals.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Animal::getSpecies, 
                Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)));
```

But Instead of the expected `Collection<Animal>` I would suggest to use another type like `List<Animal>`:

```
Map<String, List<Animal>> collect = animals.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Animal::getSpecies));
```